# ¿Como cambio a través de un ComboBox, el estilo de fuente de las cosas que escribo en un cuadro de texto automáticamente?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<ComboBox Width="120" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" x:Name="combosize"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}"/>

<TextBox Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"   AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"  Name="myTextBox" KeyUp="myTextBox_KeyUp" TextChanged="myTextBox_TextChanged></TextBox>
```

PD: Recien empiezo con WPF

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: Con "estilo de fuente" te refieres a las propiedades de la fuente (que sea negrita, cursiva, tamaño, tamaño, alineación, wrapping)? o también a la fuente en si?

Answer (score 0):

Para que se cambie el tipo de letra del TextBox cuando seleccionas la fuente en el ComboBox, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="combo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}" />
        <TextBox FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=combo, Path=SelectedValue}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Un saludo.